# React + Typescript - defining component props when component is conditionally rendered

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given the following situation:

```
{ this.props.userName && <UserProfile userName={this.props.userName} />
```

and in `UserProfile`:

```
interface UserProfileProps {
  userName: string;
}

class UserProfile extends React.Component<UserProfileProps>
```

The first line of the question gives me the error:

`[ts] Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

My question is: Is there a way to let typescript know that the component will not render if the prop is null? Thus, not making me have to defined it's type as `string | null` since it will never be called with null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! By using the `!` postfix operator explained [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
{ this.props.userName && <UserProfile userName={this.props.userName!} />}
```